# git push Heroku "Precompiling assets failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I try and push my rails app to Heroku, I get the following problem:

```
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 50f04b554cf0d361879bf0f70d7c445ed0c3a480
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 50f04b554cf0d361879bf0f70d7c445ed0c3a480
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to defaceme.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/defaceme.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/defaceme.git'
edithkenny@Georginas-MBP defaceme %
```

I have updates my username on my computer, im not sure if this affected my terminal...Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain why the warnings from Heroku don't apply to your situation?